# Plugin class ...\DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, checkout, plugin, magento2.2.3

I'm trying to create a plugin for `DirectoryDataProcessor.php` but I can't seem to get the `di.xml` to work. The LayoutProcessor in `di.xml` works.

I get the following error:

```
Plugin class BB\Checkout\Plugin\Block\DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin doesn't exist.
```

> *etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="bb_checkout" type="BB\Checkout\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
 </type>

<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor">
    <plugin name='bb_checkout_req' 
 type='BB\Checkout\Plugin\Block\DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin' 
 sortOrder='99'/>
</type>
```

> */BB/Checkout/Plugin/Block/DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin.php*

```
<?php

 namespace BB\Checkout\Plugin\Block\Checkout;

 class DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin
 {
/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor $subject
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 */
public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {

    return $jsLayout;
}
}
```

I tried changing the name and folder structure many times and have no clue on how to fix this. I just started working with Magento 2.

I also tried putting DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin in **plugin/block** instead of **plugin/block/checkout**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misplacing your file

In di.xml you have defined

```
type='BB\Checkout\Plugin\Block\DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin'
```

where as you have shown the directory path of your file as

```
/BB/Checkout/Plugin/Block/Checkout/DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin.php
```

Move your file out of **Checkout** directory and check.

Comment: You're right but sadly that doesn't fix the error :(

Comment: You also need to change the namespace inside your plugin file. `namespace BB\Checkout\Plugin\Block;`

Comment: Ah that was it Priyank! Thanks changed the namespace to namespace BigBridge\Checkout\Plugin\Block; and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `etc/di.xml` code with following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="bb_checkout" type="BB\Checkout\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
 </type>

<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor">
    <plugin name='bb_checkout_req' 
 type='BB\Checkout\Plugin\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin' 
 sortOrder='99'/>
</type>
```

You missed `Checkout` on above XML it should be like `BB\Checkout\Plugin\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin`.

After replacing with above code if it's still not working that I'll suggest you to check the file permission.

Hope it'll help you.